# Highlight matched words MySQL FULLTEXT index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, hit-highlighting

MySQL FULLTEXT index trouble.
There are:

1. Table with words like:

| ID | WORDS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `jfjdeur,rjjghfje,rioogr` |
| 2 | `fkjtifdfe,lerkr` |
| 3 | `kfrkriti` |
| 4 | `frlerkti,tykitriero,frorodfl,rfjkrjr` |
|  | ... |
| N | `fjfjtiu,frkrker,fkdkri` |

2. MySQL FULLTEXT index on WORDS column.
3. Query like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE match(`words`) against ('gjfjdeur,rioogr,tykitriero')
```

As the result returns:

| ID | WORDS |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `gjfjdeur,rjjghfje,rioogr` | (because contains `gjfjdeur` and `rioogr`) |
| 4 | `frlerkti,tykitriero,frorodfl,rfjkrjr` | (because contains `tykitriero`) |

Is it possible to rewrite query to create additional column which will be contain found/matched word? Something like:

| ID | WORDS | FOUND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `gjfjdeur,rjjghfje,rioogr` | `gjfjdeur,rioogr` |
| 4 | `frlerkti,tykitriero,frorodfl,rfjkrjr` | `tykitriero` |

Maybe something like:

```sql
SELECT *, some_function_to_select_matched_range(`word`) as found
FROM `table`
WHERE match(`words`) against ('gjfjdeur,rioogr,tykitriero')
```

In realily, `table.words` consists of hundreds words and `preg_match_all` in php isn't a good solution to select the matched words from each found.

Comment: FYI, you're missing `WHERE` in your queries.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any easy way to do this. I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252935/fulltext-search-and-highlighting-by-php-and-mysql but the answers there just suggest `preg_replace`.

Comment: have you looked into splitting the words into rows to query off of? that may be a lot easier